# Second Instance Of Object Not Working Correctly

Tags: c++, instance

So I'm working on an example from my class textbook *Starting Out With C++: Early Objects*, and I'm running into an issue. I'm instructed to create a program that reads in some data and prints it at the end, 2 instances in total. When the second instance (md2) runs, it it doesn't let me enter anything in the first field. This is really bugging me, and I can't figure it out. Thanks in advance!

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class MovieData
{
private:
    string movieTitle;
    string movieDirector;
    int movieYear;
    int movieRunTime;
public:
    MovieData()
    {
        GetTitle();
        GetDirector();
        GetYear();
        GetRunTime();
    }

    void GetTitle()
    {
        cout << "Specify A Title\n";
        getline(cin, movieTitle);
        cout << endl;
    }
    void GetDirector()
    {
        cout << "Specify A Director" << endl;
        getline(cin, movieDirector);
        cout << endl;
    }
    void GetYear()
    {
        cout << "Specify A Year" << endl;
        cin >> movieYear;
        cout << endl;
    }
    void GetRunTime()
    {
        cout << "Specify A Duration In Minutes" << endl;
        cin >> movieRunTime;
        cout << endl;
    }

    void SetTitle()
    {
        cout << "R" << movieTitle << endl;
    }
    void SetDirector()
    {
        cout << "R" << movieDirector << endl;
    }
    void SetYear()
    {
        cout << "R" << movieYear << endl;
    }
    void SetRunTime()
    {
        cout << "R" << movieRunTime << endl;
    }


};

void PrintData(MovieData md);

int main() {
    MovieData md1;
    PrintData(md1);
    MovieData md2;
    PrintData(md2);
}


void PrintData(MovieData md)
{
    md.SetTitle();
    md.SetDirector();
    md.SetYear();
    md.SetRunTime();
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Side note: don't you need to instantiate the object?

Comment: @BlackFrog In Java or C#, each object is a pointer, so you need to initialize `MovieData` with the `new` command. (i.e. `MovieData md1 = new MovieData()`. This example is C++. In C++, simply declaring an instance of the class will invoke the constructor.

Comment: Yes, I thought that's what you meant. I remember that from those languages, but was wondering why you'd mentioned it lol.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason why this happens is that the last item that you read from end-user when preparing `md1` is an `int`. End-user types that integer in, and then presses <kbd>Enter</kbd>. C++ reads the integer into `movieRunTime`, but leaves the character code for <kbd>Enter</kbd> *buffered* for the next read.

The next time around, that enter character code gets returned to `GetTitle`, meaning that the title becomes an empty string. That is the behavior that you are observing.

To fix this problem, add a call to [`std::cin.ignore`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) to your constructor:

```
MovieData()
{
    GetTitle();
    GetDirector();
    GetYear();
    GetRunTime();
    std::cin.ignore(256, '\n');
}
```

Comment: @karite36 I think that learning what's going on was a big part of your assignment. Effects of buffering will come up in multiple places on both input and output, so it's very useful to understand what's going on here.

Comment: Didn't notice the check mark. It worked. We never covered buffering, and it wasn't in the chapter the problem was in. See what happens when the school uses separate books every term? Incoherence.